# What does this Holder<> do in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Can someone please explain this code?

```
public void getSupplierByZipCode(
    @WebParam(name = "zip", targetNamespace = "http://www.webservicex.net/")
    String zip,
    @WebParam(name = "GetSupplierByZipCodeResult", targetNamespace =  "http://www.webservicex.net/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<Boolean> getSupplierByZipCodeResult,
    @WebParam(name = "SupplierDataLists", targetNamespace = "http://www.webservicex.net/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<SupplierDataList> supplierDataLists);
```

I've never seen `Holder` before in Java.  What are `Holder<Boolean>` and `Holder<SupplierDataList>` in the function?  Are they like outputs??  I need the supplier data list from this function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [Holder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/ws/Holder.html) - The entire purpose is to "hold a value" *while allowing side-effect modifications of itself* (and thus change value it "holds").

The instance variable (`value`) representing the contained/"held" value can be *reassigned*; this is used to facilitate how [multiple] values are "returned" in the WS - through explicit modification of the holders supplied as parameters. (Note the usage of `WebParam.Mode.OUT` as well.)

This "extra layer" is required because Java is *always* [Call By Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value); the Holder then effectively fakes a pointer-indirection (let's call it "reference-indirection"), as what might be done in C, which leads to [Call By (Object) Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) semantics.

Imagine:

```
// Outside WS function - setup parameters and invoke
String zip = "98682";
Holder<Boolean> result = new Holder<Boolean>();
getSupplierByZipCode(zip, result, ..);

// Then inside the function the Holder is modified and a new value
// is assigned to it's value member.
getSupplierByZipCodeResult.value = true;

// And outside again, the mutations are visibile still
if (result.value) {
    // Yay!
}
```

Since strings are immutable and the zip is *not* wrapped in a Holder then the zip code cannot be changed (or "returned" by) the WS call.

See also:

- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)
- [How to implement int in/out params in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355404/how-to-implement-int-in-out-params-in-java)

Comment: But if i want to get supplierdatalists, how do i access it??what should i pass as arguments for functions?

Comment: @SparshithP Same way; follow the template given in the usage of the `result` variable. Supply a `Holder<SupplierDataList>` (since it is only an OUT parameter, no initial holder value must be supplied) which can be modified to "return" a value in the WS method. Then use the `value` after the call.